# How to make ASImageNode size same as image or remove transparent reminder?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textures, asyncdisplaykit

If my image bigger than view size, I have empty space inside ASImageNode. Now on a image below, I have empty space from the left and right of content. How I can reduce width of ASImageNode?
So basically ASImageNode same size as parent View, but I don't need it!
Origin Image size bigger than parent View. ASImageNode aspectRatioFit was set

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the preferredSize of ASImageNode instance to make it take lesser space.

```
imageNode.style.preferredSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
```